# Pregunta sobre descuentos en java

Tags: java, eclipse

Tengo el siguiente enunciado:

> Diseña e implemente el siguiente
>    programa: – Decidir (usarconstantes):
>
> ● Cuál es el valor mínimo para optar al descuento ● Cuánto se
>   descontará Cuál es el valor máximo posible ● – Pedir el precio
>   inicial, en euros – Leerlo – Comprobar no es negativo: ● En caso
>   cierto, ver si el precio introducido es mayor o igual al valor mínimo
>   para optar  al descuento – En este caso, calcular el descuento –
>   Comprobar si el descuento supera el máximo permisible ● Si es cierto,
>   el descuento se reduce al máximo permisible – Aplicar el descuento
>   sobre el precio inicial – Mostrar el precio final Si el precio era
>   negativo, mostrar un mensaje de error.

He hecho esto, pero no me funciona

```
package practicas;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Practica5 {//las constantes siempre se introducen antes del main

private static final double VALOR_MINIMO = 20;

private static final double DESCUENTO = 0.5;

private static final double VALOR_MAXIMO = 40;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int numero;
    double precio;
    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);


    System.out.println("Â¿cual es el precio inicial? \n");
    precio = teclado.nextDouble();

    if (precio < 0) {
        System.out.println("El nÃºmero es incorrecto");

    } else if (precio >= VALOR_MINIMO) {

        double cantidadADescontar = precio * DESCUENTO;

        if (cantidadADescontar > VALOR_MAXIMO) {
            cantidadADescontar= VALOR_MAXIMO;
        }   

        precio = precio - cantidadADescontar;
        System.out.println("El precio es" + precio);

    }

}
}
```

Comment: Hola marxal, ¿qué error te genera la consola? Yo he lanzado el código en mi entorno y funciona sin problemas cumpliendo los puntos del ejercicio.

Comment: _No me funciona_ no proporciona ningún tipo de información. Te lanza alguna excepción? Te genera resultados inesperados? Pulsa en [edit] y añade toda esta información para que sea mas fácil poder ayudarte

Comment: No es que salte error, lo que no se es si está bien hecho

Comment: Si cumple lo que te pide el enunciado, está bien hecho. Si no lo cumple, especifíca (con datos concretos) que datos introduces, que datos esperas, y que datos obtienes.

Comment: El problema es que no cumple, si saca un descuento, pero el normal no